# Does Apple Mail verify message has been moved to new folder before deleting it from old folder?

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail

I am using Apple Mail and switch email providers. I want to Move my messages from one account to another. I need to be confident that when I move (not Copy) messages from one account to another account using Apple Mail, that the messages are truly on the new account before they are deleted from the old account.

Does Apple Mail verify the new message has been stored (committed) to the new account before it deletes it from the old account?

Thank you.

Comment: So copy them, then delete them.  Also, many providers can import from another provider.

Comment: Thanks, I realize I can do that, but I want to move them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through my own testing, I have been able to confirm that Apple Mail will return mail to the original folder if there are any issues moving it to the new account/folder.

At first, Apple Mail will show the mail message(s) as deleted from the original folder, then if/when an issue occurs that prevents the message(s) from being saved to the new account/folder, the message(s) will be returned to the original account/folder.